# Cannot find custom menu and sidebar in the published add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to publish a Google Sheet add-on with the `unlisted` option: `Only people with the link can see it`. Here is the code: `Code.gs`:

```
function myFun() {
  return "myFunValue"
}

function onInstall() {
  onOpen()
}

function onOpen() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html') //your html page name
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Use in this spreadsheet', 'use')
      .addToUi();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function use() {
  var title = 'Date Custom Functions';
  var message = 'Message of use';
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(title, message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

`Index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    super add-on, with custom function "=myFun()" and custom menu
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/functionmenuside/bmojfiljhggogegocdkjdlaoohbkcmod?authuser=0

This add-on works on its own Google Sheet. However, after publishing, when I click on `+Free`, it opens a new Google Sheet, I can find `FunctionMenuSide` in the `Add-ons`. The custom function works, whereas there is no sidebar, and we cannot find the custom menu `Use in this spreadsheet`. It seems that `onOpen` is not executed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1:**, in the console, there are messages: 
`1739997376-ritz_waffle_integrated_i18n_ritzmaestro.js:105 Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to call createHtmlOutputFromFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the sidebar in the `onOpen()` function. This won't work because of the way that simple triggers work with Google Apps Script.

Instead, create another function that opens the sidebar and adds that function as an item in your add-on menu. Then your user can open the sidebar themselves from the add-on menu.

Comment: "This won't work because of the way that simple triggers work with Google Apps Script." ==> It seems that sometimes the sidebar can be opened automatically, sometimes not... Why?

Comment: Shoot. Well if it is opening sometimes I have no idea how to explain that. The documentation that I was looking at was: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen